# How to check whether an instance variable is assigned or not in ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have the following 2 classes who's attributes will be set in some other client class. If the instance variables of these classes are not assigned I want to make sure I don't make it inside of the `if` condition such as `if(@lte)`. Do I need to explicitly check for `.empty?`, or `.nil?` or `.blank?` etc? what's recommended to check against unassigned instance variables?

```
# ==== range filter ====
class Range < QueryModel

    query_hash = {}
    attr_accessor :search_field, :range_criteria

    def serialize
        if(@search_field)
            query_hash[@search_field] = @range_criteria.serialize
            query_hash[:range] = self.query_hash
        end
    end

end

class RangeCriteria < QueryModel

    query_hash = {}
    attr_accessor :gte, :lte

    def serialize
        if(@gte)
            query_hash[:gte] = @gte
        end

        if(@lte)
            query_hash[:lte] = @lte
        end

        if(@gte != nil || @lte != nil) 
            return query_hash
        end

    end


end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be obvious that you can't determine whether or not a variable was assigned by dereferencing the variable. Why? Well, either trying to dereference a variable that hasn't been assigned will be an error (in which case your code will break), or it will evaluate to some default object, in which case you won't know whether it evaluated to that object because the variable was unassigned or because someone assigned that object to that variable.

In Ruby, both things can happen, depending on the kind of variable:

```
UnassignedConstant.nil?
# Boom! NameError

@unassigned_instance_variable.nil?
# => true
# but is it true because it was unassigned or because someone assigned nil?
```

Either way, simple logic tells us that calling a method on the variable *cannot* possibly answer our question. We can't dereference our variable to figure out whether it was assigned. We have to look for some other way, for some reflective method which takes a variable as an argument (more precisely, which takes *the name of a variable* as an argument; methods can't take variables as arguments in Ruby, because variables aren't objects and you can only take objects as arguments). Thankfully, there are a number of such methods:

- [`Module#const_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F)
- [`Module#class_variable_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_defined-3F)
- [`Binding#local_variable_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_defined-3F)
- [`Object#instance_variable_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_defined-3F)

[BTW: Note that there is no corresponding method for global variables, I have no idea why.]

In your case, you obviously want the latter:

```
def serialize
  if instance_variable_defined?(:@gte)
    query_hash[:gte] = @gte
  end

  if instance_variable_defined?(:@lte)
    query_hash[:lte] = @lte
  end

  unless @gte.nil? && @lte.nil?
    query_hash
  end
end
```

[Note that there are other problems with your code, such as `query_hash` being undefined, but those are out of scope of this question.]

Comment: thank you. what you mean query_hash is undefined? I define it in each class don't I?

Comment: Yes, you define it as a local variable of the class declaration body, but you use it as a local variable of the method body. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, that's why they are called local variables. A class body and a method body are different scopes, so the two `query_hash`es are two different local variables.

Comment: Thank you. So how should I define this variable? Inside of the initialize? Does it have to be an instance variable though? Or could i place this inside of the QueryModel parent class? Please clarify these doubts! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.present?`

It's basically the opposite of `.empty?`

Answer (score 0):

`.blank?` is pretty common, but keep in mind that an empty string and false will result in true which may not be what you want.  In which case you may want to use `.nil?` or similar.

```
> "".blank?
=> true
> false.blank?
=> true
```

Comment: .blank? is present on rails apps. another way to do blank? function is ask for    var.nil? || var.empty?

Comment: don't you think .present? would be a better use for this situation? These are my own class objects, not strings.

Comment: `.present?` would also be fine. You still have the same issues around blank strings and false though.  I don't know your use case though so don't know if those matter.